# How to map kinect skeleton onto avatar joints by Unity3D

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, kinect, avatar

I want to know how to map kinect skeleton to a 3D avatar joints by unity3D, I use kinect v2, I design a humanoid figure in .obj, is there any tutorial for beginner?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: probably it was a plugin at the Unity assetsstore for work with kinect (Kinect v2 Examples with MS-SDK), may be you will be better to look at it.